# Google home integration with dynamo DB

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-home, google-smart-home

I am creating Google Smart Home action of google home. But I have not idea, how to connect the dynamo DB with smart home action but I can see here using with firebase. When I ran the command with invocation name in google assistant then it is showing "something went wrong".

I have enabled the home graph API and also created the JSON key file. I also can see their upload JS file button but don't know, what files should I upload there?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are going through the [Washer codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/smarthome-washer), which is a great first step.

When you are [configuring your project in the Actions console](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/create), you would need to enter your fulfillment URL from your application (rather than the Firebase URLs shown in the codelab).

You also need to set up an [authentication server](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/implement-oauth#implement_oauth_account_linking) to enable account linking. Once you've completed this, you should be able to test your Smart Home Action through the Google Home app. Remember that you need to configure the console with your application's URLs for authorization and tokens in place of the demo URLs in the codelab.

The JS upload you are seeing in the console is for [local fulfillment applications](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/local#before_you_begin), which would be a feature to consider adding after you have successfully uploaded and tested your Smart Home Action.